# What's this math concept visualized in this math poster including Euclid?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

What's this math concept visualized in this math poster including Euclid?

[image]

It looks similar to what I've seen in algebra regarding groups and their visualization, but aren't groups much more modern concept?

Comment: I found this on one of the websites as a comment by someone (https://io9.gizmodo.com/fetching-minimalist-prints-honor-mathematicians-and-the-493104850) --  image from Euclid's poster would better suit Euler. The image is of a graph, which is an area of mathematics that Euler helped pioneer.

Comment: @geekyme Graph of what?

Comment: This Wolfram page though gives examples of exactly the kind of visualization that I've seen in algebra and group theory: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/GraphTheory.html

Comment: Looks like one of these projections of a regular polygon onto the plane. Not my area at all, but from a superficial search I could find such an image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_22_polytope). I’m pretty sure that this has nothing to do with Euclid.

Comment: You could always [ask the artist, Hydrogene](http://hydrogeneportfolio.tumblr.com/post/49123429292/minimal-posters-five-great-mathematicians-and).

Comment: @k.stm Yea it looks like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_22_polytope#/media/File:Up_1_22_t0_E6.svg.

Answer (score 0):

It's a six dimensional polytope called the $1_{22}$ polytope.  Probably discovered somewhat after Euclid's time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_22_polytope

(This has been pointed out twice in the comments.  Posting this to get this question out of the unanswered category.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a regular dodecagon (12-sided polygon), together with all its diagonals except (for some reason) those that go through the centre. The whole diagram can be constructed using classical means.